# encfs decryption, filename encoding 'nameio/block' 4.0.0 not supported

Tags: linux, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt an encfs folder, but when executing the command I get the following error:

```
(FileUtils.cpp:1649) Unable to find nameio interface nameio/block, version 4:0:0
```

The command I use for mounting is simply:

```
encfs ~/encrypted_folder ~/mount_point
```

I've tried with sudo or --forcedecode, got same result.

the output for the encfsctl command over the encrypted folder is:

```
Version 6 configuration; created by EncFS 1.7.5 (revision 20100713)
Filesystem cipher: "ssl/aes", version 3:0:0 (using 3:0:2)
Filename encoding: "nameio/block", version 4:0:0 (NOT supported)
Key Size: 256 bits
Using PBKDF2, with 1351653 iterations
Salt Size: 160 bits
Block Size: 1024 bytes, including 8 byte MAC header
Each file contains 8 byte header with unique IV data.
Filenames encoded using IV chaining mode.
File data IV is chained to filename IV.
File holes passed through to ciphertext.
```

My OS details are:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with kernel  3.13.0-35-generic
```

I'm pretty lost, I don't know what is that encoding and why is not supported. Searching on google does not give me any solutions...

Comment: It seems I've found the answer... when reviewing the question I saw I'm using encfs 1.7.4, but the folder was created with 1.7.5. I'll let you know if that was the solution when I update encfs binaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confimed: using encfs 1.7.5 solves the problem.